# Inno Setup Compiler: add page option selected according

Tags: inno-setup

I want to display a custom page only if the option of an earlier page is activated, for example, i have this code:

```
[Code]
var page_option : TInputOptionWizardPage;
    page_dir_se : TInputDirWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
    page_option := CreateInputOptionPage(1,'Select','','',False,True);
    page_option.Add('Option 1');
    page_option.Add('Option 2');

    page_dir_se :=CreateInputDirPage(page_option.ID,'Select', '','',False, '');
    page_dir_se.Add('Select A');
    page_dir_se.Add('Select B');
    page_dir_se.Add('Select C');

end;
```

In the ​​example only if page_option.Values[0] is TRUE page_dir_se should show me, and if page_option.Values​​[1] is TRUE then should show me another page.

I use Inno Setup Compiler

Thankz for help.
Regards xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can skip any page in the [`ShouldSkipPage`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=ShouldSkipPage) event:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
var
  DirPage: TInputDirWizardPage;
  OptionPage: TInputOptionWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  OptionPage := CreateInputOptionPage(wpWelcome, 'Caption', 'Description',
    'SubCaption', False, True);
  OptionPage.Add('Option 1');
  OptionPage.Add('Option 2');

  DirPage := CreateInputDirPage(OptionPage.ID, 'Caption', 'Description',
    'SubCaption', False, '');
  DirPage.Add('Select A');
  DirPage.Add('Select B');
  DirPage.Add('Select C');
end;

function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  // skip the page if your custom dir page is about to show and
  // the option is not checked
  Result := (PageID = DirPage.ID) and not OptionPage.Values[0];
end;
```

Comment: That's right, the code works, however if the user returns to the selection options and uncheck the option 1 (.values[0]) and click on next button the code no longer works, it's as if you did not upgrade the value.

Comment: That's what I *fixed* in my post update. Try the current script.